# WSO2 ESB connectivity CICS Transaction Server

Tags: mainframe, zos, cics, wso2-esb

Need to know if WSO2 ESB can integrate with CICS Transaction Server v 3.2 on a z/OS mainframe.
TIA.

Comment: Google finds a "case study". Any use to you?

Comment: That case study assumes CICS Transaction Gateway. CTG != CTS (CICS Transaction Server)

Comment: There are not many hits on Google. Means less likely you'll get someone here who knows. Perhaps you have to contact IBM and ask, and WSO2 and ask. Or go through the docs and try it out...

Answer (score 0):

CICS Transaction Server v3.2 can support standard SOAP over http calls.  Is there an need for your ESB to actually know it is integrating with CICS or can you get by with a wsdl document with an endpoint at a CICS server behaving like any other webservices provider?

Comment: We are not assuming CICS socket, HTTP, webservices or MQ support. Evidently what you are referring to is the CICS Webservices assistance batch files or the Rational Devz approach for generating WSBINDING files etc.. etc..

Please provide me your thoughts based on your assumptions which could be based on all or few of the above or maybe based on something I have not listed above. 

Thanks.

Comment: No RD/z required, though it supports it.  CICS has a native SOAP interface since TS v2.3