# Legstar module for mainframe connectivity

Tags: esb, mainframe, zos

We don't have CICS Tx Gateway installed but do have CICS Tx Server. I want to know if [Legstar](http://www.legsem.com/) can connect from an ESB like (Mule,Camel,JBossESB,WSO2) to the z/OS mainframe using this module to CICS Transaction Server. Alternatively, if there are other options to connect to the mainframe, feel free to suggest.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I saw in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780152/wso2-esb-connectivity-cics-transaction-server) of your several questions on this topic that you are using CICS TS 3.2; there is a section in the documentation germane to the discussion called [Connecting CICS to the Web](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=configuring-cics-web-support-components).  Documentation for later versions and releases of CICS TS are available [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=what-documentation-is-available).

As Joe Zitzelberger indicates, you can use raw TCP/IP sockets (we have done this since CICS TS version 1 more than a decade ago), REST/POX (we have done this since version 2.1 which we started using in 2006), and SOAP (available via a support pack in 2.3 and built into the product since 3.1).

You can also talk to CICS via MQ.

More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211623/624463).

Update per comment from OP: These are realtime synchronous interactions.  In our case, response time is subsecond.

Comment: Our CICS interaction is mainly real-time/synchronous for our current use case(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a direct connection to CICS/TS with SOAP over HTTP to execute your CICS transactions and to return your data.

Comment: Will this work with CICS TS ? Does the webservices enablement need to be done or do the following work out of the box : CICS sockets, HTTP, Webservice ?

Comment: All of that is built in since CICS/TS 2.3 or 3.1 I believe.

Comment: Are there some steps which need to be done to enable webservices support in CICS TS v3.2 or v4.2 (we have a planned upgrade next quarter)